# Auto increment variable inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, auto-increment

I have a procedure that saves the answers from users who reply to a survey. My database has 3 tables SurveyData, SurveyQuestions and SurveyAnswers.

SurveyData stores data from the user

```
IdData || Name || Ocupation
```

SurveyQuestions has all the available questions

```
IdQuestion || Question
1          || question 1
2          || question 2 ...
```

And SurveyAnswers, that stores the replies given by the user

```
IdData || IdQuestion || Answer
```

I have a total of 10 questions in my database, what i want to do is the StoredProcedure to insert in the IdQuestion column values from 1 to 10, and when another user replies to restart that count from 1 to 10 again

This is my current SP

```
USE [Surveys]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [usurvey].[InsertSurvey] ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [usurvey].[InsertSurvey] @Name varchar(50), @Ocupation varchar(50), @replies varchar(2000)
as begin
DECLARE @idData int
declare @posreply int
declare @reply varchar(20)
    begin
    INSERT INTO SurveyData(Name,Ocupation)
    VALUES (@Name,@Ocupation)
    SET @idData=(SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY])

    end
    if (@replies <> '')
    begin
        while PATINDEX ('%|%', @replies) <> 0
        begin
            select @posreply = PATINDEX('%|%',@replies)
            select @reply = left(@replies,@posreply -1)
            insert into SurveyAnswers (idData, idQuestion, Answer)
            select @idData,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by (select null)),@reply
            select @replies = STUFF(@replies, 1, @posreply,'')
        end
    end
END
```

When I execute the SP

```
exec InsertarSurvey @Name = 'john', @Ocupation = 'teacher' , @respuestas = 'almost never|never|always|'
```

This is the result of the execution

```
IdData || IdQuestion || Answer
1      || 1          || almost never
1      || 1          || never
1      || 1          || always
```

And this is the results I want to get

```
IdData || IdQuestion || Answer
1      || 1          || almost never
1      || 2          || never
1      || 3          || always
```

And if someone else completes the survey

```
IdData || IdQuestion || Answer
1      || 1          || almost never
1      || 2          || never
1      || 3          || always
2      || 1          || never
2      || 2          || never
2      || 3          || almost always
```

Comment: what version of sql server?

Comment: and do you need to maintain the order of the replies?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a loop, you could leverage the STRING_SPLIT in conjunction with the ROW_NUMBER function.

```
DECLARE @replies varchar(2000) = 'almost never|never|always|'
SELECT value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by (select null)) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@replies,'|')
```